# Static resources are no more available after spring security is enabled

Tags: java, spring, security

I fighting with some configuration that my static resources (js, css etc) in spring application are no more available. Can some body point out what am i missing.  Here is the code.  Note my JS and CSS are in following folders. Also note that before enabling spring security these resources were accessible

```
Web Pages ->
     WEB-INF ->
          resources ->
                and here 2 folders js and css
```

in my JSP Page i want to access jquery in js folder with following link

```
<script src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and the error in browser is

Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8010/resources/js/js.js the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling     // if you want certain function running on the backend on recurrning basis like very 5 second a function call itself  then you have to ensbale this.  this will enable all classes defined as Service and Scheduled to be running on backend automatically. see example in  com.outbottle.controllers.ScheduledTasks.java
@ComponentScan("com.outbottle, com.JavaAnatatedClass")   //this will import all beans marked as  @Controller, or @Repository, or @Service, or @Component  in the application context
@ImportResource({"classpath:beans1.xml"})   //this will import all beans in the application context from this xml file
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

    @Bean  
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {  
           .....
           .....
    }  

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/**");

    }
```

Here is the security configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationService as = new AuthenticationService();    
        auth.userDetailsService(as);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/REST").permitAll() 
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")    //you have to use hasAuthority because in AuthenticationService you are using GrantedAuthority object.    i replaced hasRole with hasAuthority.     check the detailes below in comments
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN') and hasAuthority('DBA')")

        //Custom Login Form with fields and values
        //.and().formLogin()      //this will show default spring login page
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")    //these aret the fields on the login page for user and password 
        .and().csrf()              
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some hit and try and found this works

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/js/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/css/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/css/");
```

for some reasons   /WEB-INF/resources/js/*  or   **    not working

Also i am individually adding each directory to resources.

Shahzad

Comment: Normally a browser should not be able to get things from /WEB-INF. It however can explicitly be delivered by handlers. I would place them in the webapp directory immediately / like /resources/js.